# Calling an API and synchronising database

Tags: synchronization, locks

I am calling a payments API to send a payment.

At the same time, I need to mark the payment as sent in my database.

If I call the API first, then the database crashes, the payment will be sent twice.

If I save to the database first and the API request fails, the payment won't be sent.

What's a good solution to this? Is an edge case like this even something to worry about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is essentially a *distributed transaction*, and it is a very tricky thing to get right, if at all possible.

There are a couple of things you could do. First, you could try to send the payment in a *idempotent* way if the external API supports it. That just means, that you won't duplicate the transaction. This can be done by passing some unique transaction ID, if supported.

If the transaction is idempotent, you can try it as many times as you like, until it works, or until you run out of tries. Note: if you stop trying, you still need to make sure the external system did not in fact execute after you stopped trying.

If this is not available, and if your part of the state is stable (it doesn't change), then you could try to wait until there is a definite state on the other side. Until you can confirm either the acceptance or rejection of your previous request. This is basically a "sync" algorithm.

Either way, distributed transaction and/or sync is not trivial. In the generic case it is actually impossible to solve ([CAP Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem)).

It is in fact so complicated and costly to implement in some cases, that some companies just don't do it, and instead rely on customer support to sort out edge cases. I've heard the phrase "*apology based computing*" to describe this strategy.

Comment: Thank you. Since the transactions are actually crypto transactions, I'll have a transaction field, populate that first and have a seperate task to send it out and then mark it as completed. That way the worst case scenario is it gets sent several times (not marked as completed) or the API is down but then it'll never be marked as completed- so the state is "safe" either way.

Comment: @Lolums Crypto transactions should be idempotent. You should be able to generate the transaction once, store it in the database, and then resend that exact transaction as many times as you want and the network knows it's the same transaction and won't process it more than once. (It *can't* process it more than once, anyway, because the transaction says *which specific bitcoin* you want to spend and you can't spend it more than once)

Answer (score 0):

Whether you write to the database or not depends on the response you receive from your API request. (i.e., if the payment is successful, you write to the database, else you don't) This is something that should concern you as it is essential for maintaining your system's consistency.